# Wavesurfer.js fails when using map function: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: reactjs, wavesurfer.js

Audio waveform generation and playback component using [Wavesurfer.js](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) renders the first item in an array fine, but fails when rendering subsequent items.

[image: this error]

[Code](https://github.com/pravda23/jbcomv3/blob/main/src/components/Audio.component.js)

[Wavesurfer.js docs](https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/) show that the container element for a single waveform component should be included as a property in the return statement. However, the container element is not being updated with each pass of the map loop.

Are renders failing because we're triggering the first render successfully (using useEffect) and subsequent ones are unable to "find" the correct container element?

Here's the [Wavesurfer example code for a single waveform using React](https://wavesurfer-js.org/examples/?react.js). I'm unable to find examples of apps using multiple Wavesurfer waveforms, which would be super useful.